# Browser How to maximize the browser automatically while playback

Tags: rft

How to maximize the browser automatically while playback the web application script in rational functional tester(Rational Functional Tester)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `maximize()` on the BrowserTestObject:

```
startApp("Google");
browser_htmlBrowser().maximize();
```

Or record the click on the maximize Button, which gives you:

```
browser_htmlBrowser(document_google(),DEFAULT_FLAGS).maximize();
```

Comment: but we want maximize the existing browser without using browser Object like browser_htmlBrowser()...

Answer (score 0):

The following code will find the open browsers and maximize the ones found

```
void maximizeBrowsers()
{
    TestObject[] browsers =  find(atChild(".class","Html.HtmlBrowser"));

    System.out.println("Browsers found : "+ browsers.length);

    for(TestObject browser:browsers)
    {
        //add addional check if required  to get to the right browser
        ((BrowserTestObject)browser).maximize();             
    }

    unregister(browsers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

startBrowser("Internet Explorer","www.google.com");

browser_htmlBrowser().click();